# Disable enable JButton in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem I'm trying to disable JButton with setEnabled(false) like this:

```
ButtonNewCustomer.setEnabled(false);
```

But this didn't work so then I imported the Applet packages, but still not working, then I discovered that I also needed to use extends Applet in the class, but the problem is that I'm already using extends for other things like this:

```
public class GUI4EX extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
...
}
```

I have tried to add Applet, but this dont't work! Is there a way to solve this? Thanks!

EDIT: It's working know! The problem was a misspelling of the buttonNewCustomer. The first letter 'b' was 'B'. Sorry! And thanks for the help!

Comment: `setEnabled(false)` will disable, not enable, the button.  You don't need to extend Applet, not sure where you got that from.

Comment: Extend Applet - better JApplet, which is a kind of a Frame. JApplet is the Swing form, and fits to JButton. If you need a JFrame inside, create an attribute JFrame. Create a SSCE and provide complete errormessages.

Comment: There's a working solution in this thread: [How to disable javax swing jbutton in java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625855/how-to-disable-javax-swing-jbutton-in-java

Comment: I't working! Please see my edit!

Answer (score 2):

use `setEnabled(true)` to enable button...

Comment: Sorry! I made a misspelling of the button name!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are disabling/enabling your button before setting the frame's visibility.

Comment: wrong, there is no sequential dependency on setting those properties (toplevel parent visible vs. child enabled)